# Совместное использование $elemMatch и $in в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Имеется коллекция:

```
[
{
    "name": "Коля",
    "specifications": [
        { "name": "Рост", "value": 190 },
        { "name": "Вес", "value": 78 },
        { "name": "Любимое занятие", "value": "Поиск кузнечиков"}
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Вася",
    "specifications": [
        { "name": "Рост", "value": 177 },
        { "name": "Вес", "value": 80 },
        { "name": "Цвет глаз", "value": "Чёрный"},
        { "name": "Количество машин", "value": 2}
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Антоша",
    "specifications": [
        { "name": "Рост", "value": 182 },
        { "name": "Вес", "value": 90 },
        { "name": "Любимое пиво", "value": "Kozel"}
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Настя",
    "specifications": [
        { "name": "Рост", "value": 172 },
        { "name": "Вес", "value": 61 },
        { "name": "Количество зубов", "value": 32 }
    ]
}]
```

Хочу создать запрос для получения пользователей с определенными характеристиками.
Например:

```
db.getCollection("humans").find({
specifications: {
    $elemMatch: {
        $in: [{
            name: "Вес",
            value: 90
        }]
    }
}})
```

Завершается успешно, однако если я хочу, что value было массивом, запрос ничего не возвращает.

```
db.getCollection("humans").find({
specifications: {
    $elemMatch: {
        $in: [{
            name: "Вес",
            value: { $in: [90, 80]}
        }]
    }
}})
```

Как правильно оформить запрос?

Comment: попробуйте использовать вместо  последнего `$in`  => `$eq`

Comment: Поменял, не помогло

Comment: а `$or` пробовали?

Comment: Тоже самое. 0 результатов.

Comment: опишите словами, какой запрос Вы хотите сделать

Comment: Получить список всех людей с выбранными параметрами (specifications)

Answer (score 0):

Ну можна так (искать людей с определенным весом):

```
{
    specifications: {$elemMatch: {$and: [
        {name: "Вес", value: {$in: [80, 90]}}
    ]}}
}
```

Ну или даже так (искать людей с определенным весом ИЛИ определенным ростом):

```
{
    specifications: {$elemMatch: {$or: [{
        $and: [{name: "Вес"}, {value: {$in: [61, 80]}}]
    }, {
        $and: [{name: "Рост"}, {value: {$in: [190, 172]}}]
    }]}}
}
```

Смотря что надо.

В чем, собственно, проблема?))